# URL where user come from ASP.Net but have NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I want to know-from what url user come from. 
So, i use

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

But when i get only null value from MyUrl:

I have two projects-first is my aspx page, second- redirects to this first project-page with GET parameters.
But when second project redirect to first project- i have :

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

My second test project so simple:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:54287/go.aspx?id=DEFAULT");
    }
```

First and main project:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Request.ServerVariables('http_referer');

        //  Request.ServerVariables;

        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        if (id != null)
        {
         Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;

                Console.WriteLine(MyUrl);
                Response.Write("Referrer URL : " + MyUrl.AbsolutePath);
        }
    }
```

Error in :Response.Write("Referrer URL : " + MyUrl.AbsolutePath);

Comment: Your `NullReferenceException` in on `Response.Redirect` or `Request.UrlReferrer`?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there a a few errors:

Your code:

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
Console.WriteLine(MyUrl);
Response.Write("Referrer URL : " + MyUrl.AbsolutePath);
```

In the code above you get a `NullReferenceException` because `MyUrl` is `null`.

The `UrlReferer` may be null, so you have to check this like:

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
Console.WriteLine(MyUrl);
if (MyUrl != null)
   Response.Write("Referrer URL : " + MyUrl.AbsolutePath);
```

Also you can never make sure that the `UrlReferer` can have a value, if the user comes from another website you don't know if this website will provide this value, so you have first to assume the referrer is `null` (in summary never trust it).

Second, when you use `Response.Redirect` on your code ran **server-side** you don't know what is the referrer.

I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732742/asp-net-response-redirect-not-populating-url-referrer) and [this question](http://forums.asp.net/t/1109195.aspx/1) that will help you to better understand.

Comment: So,it is just client-side thing, thats i shouild use some other like cookies...?

Comment: Yes, for example a link `<a />` will automatically set the referrer. Using cookies is more adapted for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`UrlReferrer` is based off the `HTTP_REFERER` header that a browser should send. But, as with all things left up to the client, it's variable.

I know some "security" suites (like Norton's Internet Security) will strip that header, in the belief that it aids tracking user behavior. Also, I'm sure there's some Firefox extensions to do the same thing.

Bottom line is that you shouldn't trust it. Just append the url to the GET string and redirect based off that.

Reference:
[Stackover flow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149130/request-urlreferrer-null)