# UrlReferrer Code Not updating DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm basically trying to get a database to update the cookieId and date added.  I've included my code back coding and stored procedure.  It doesn't break the site, it just doesn't update the DB when I visit from a specific site and I can't figure out why.

```
public partial class LifeUniformTracking : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add(cookie.Values.CookieId);

    }

    public void Add(string CookieId)
    {
        string sproc = "LifeUniformTracking Add";
        if (!Common.EmptyNull(Request.UrlReferrer))
        {
            string RefferedFromLU = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            //01-06-2014 will add CookieID to DB if user's previous URL was lifeuniform
            //addedDate updates automatically via SSMS when CookieID is added
            if (RefferedFromLU.Contains("www.lifeuniform.com"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (DataAccess da = new DataAccess())
                    {
                        da.Set(sproc);

                        da.AddParameters("@CookieId", CookieId);

                        da.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    GeneralError err = new GeneralError(ex, ErrorLevel.Low, "Tracking     redirect from Life Uniform website", "Failed during: " + sproc, true, false);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


USE [ScrubsDev]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LifeUniformTracking Add]    Script Date:         1/10/2014 2:57:48 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LifeUniformTracking Add] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CookieId varchar(150)
AS

BEGIN 
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
insert into LifeUniformTracking(CookieID, AddedDate, IsLifeUniform)
select @CookieId, getdate(), 1

END
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors, but on a step through it jumps out of the code here:  if (!Common.EmptyNull(Request.UrlReferrer))

Comment: Then likely the UrlReferrer is null if what I'm assuming about `Common.EmptyNull` is correct.  I can't be certain because that's custom code.  UrlReferrer will only be populated if there is a client-click on a link. If there is a redirect, the referrer will be null.  Check this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732742/asp-net-response-redirect-not-populating-url-referrer

Comment: What does DataAccess look like? If it's not inserting a new row, likely it's not making a db call at all. If you post that code there may be something in it that explains the issue. My comment assumes you've stepped through the debugger and verified that the code block that calls the SP is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding braces around the name of the of the proc `string sproc = "[dbo].[LifeUniformTracking Add]"`?  The fact that there's a space in the proc name means you'll likely have to reference it with braces any time you're trying to execute it.

Comment: I may keep that suggestion in the final code but it doesn't resolve the issue.  Thanks, though.