# Navigating to a page with passing extra information, that doesn't end up in the URL

Tags: asp.net

For my ASP.NET application I have a page with a button. When that button is pressed I need to load a page and automatically execute a JS method `joinGroup()` on that page. This only happens when you press the button, normal navigation doesn't trigger the `joinGroup()`.

So in my Controller or client side I need to check for a flag, and when it's there I'd execute the `joinGroup()` JS method on pageload.

I thought of a few options:

- TempData: would work pretty good for this case, but I don't want a
  dependency on session (yet).
- URL/QueryString parameter: definitely don't want to do this. When people copy paste the link around it would make some very unexpected behaviour
- Cookie. Would be an option, but I'm a bit affraid that when something ever goes wrong, the Cookie will not be deleted by the
  client script, causing quite some unexpected damage.
- I thought about maybe something with a custom Header, but I don't think Headers survive a redirect.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

How about POSTing to that action method instead of making a GET request? This way you can submit anything you like and will not be visible in the URL. You will have to decorate the action method with the `HttpPost` attribute and add whatever paremeters you'd like...in this case boolean argument...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(bool yourFlag)
{
    return View(flag);
}
```

Then, the button that triggers this action method needs to be wrapped inside a form...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionMethod","YourController", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="True"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Navigate" />
}
```

Comment: Didn't think of that! Only that would go against that I don't want any 'Resubmit Form' accidents (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). But you made me think of some other idea (looking at the RequestReferrer), that I can try out.

Comment: Ahh never mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732742/asp-net-response-redirect-not-populating-url-referrer

Comment: Doesn't that fall into the querystring category?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I removed the comment. Dirk, if form re-submission is something you need to guard yourself from, then you will need to implement some logic to prevent data-corruption or any other catastrophic issues. You can't just drop form submission simply because users can refresh the page, why not persist this state, flag or whatever it is, save it in a database or somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
    void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","joinGroup()",true);
  }
```